# How to use Axios Delete in VueJs?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

Why my delete function is not working in VueJS? 
I have a table that displays the data from NodeJS and renders to VueJS

```
<tr v-for="result in filteredPeople" :key="result.id">
          <td>{{result.Memb_ID}}</td>
          //other data

          <div class="btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Edit Details</button>
            <b-button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteData(result.Memb_ID)">Delete</b-button>
          </div>
```

and my delete data is shown below.

```
deleteData(result, Memb_ID) {
  axios
    .delete("localhost:9000/api/delete/user/" + result.Memb_ID)
    .then(response => {
      this.result.splice(Memb_ID, 1);
      console.log(this.result);
    });
},
```

**On my server console**

DELETE /api/delete/user/undefined 404 167 - 0.184 ms

This is my image of backend
[image: image 2]

I never posted all the code but if you want I'll post it. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT** 
I added image of my backend.

**EDIT 2**
I updated the server image.

Comment: Is there an error? and can you show your backend side please.

Comment: Hi @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol there is it says DELETE /api/delete/user/undefined 404 167 - 0.184 ms.

Comment: You appear to have omitted the URL scheme (ie `http://` / `https://`). Try `axios.delete('http://...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are passing your `memId` via `req.params` but in your backend you are using `req.query.memId`

you can adjust it by:

1. update your axios to use `localhost:9000/api/delete/user?Memb_ID=${Memb_ID}`
2. or update your backend route to `router.delete('/delete/user/:Memb_ID')`

Comment: @Vin did you also change the `req.query.Memb_ID` in the query to `req.params.Memb_ID` ?

Comment: you `result.Memb_ID` is undefined in your axios. log it

Comment: Hi I fixed the problem by following your advice, I tweaked something too but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `deleteData` function parameter is only one. Could you try this.

```
deleteData(memId) {
  axios
    .delete("localhost:9000/api/delete/user/" + memId)
    .then(response => {
      this.result.splice(memId, 1);
      console.log(this.result);
    });
},
```

Comment: It gets the memberID but still it doesn't work. Here is in console DELETE http://localhost:9000/api/delete/user/87456 404 (Not Found)